# In c# code cleanup, How to stop visual studio 2022 adding comments /* Unmerged change from project 'xxxx (net6.0)'

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn-code-analysis, code-cleanup

Environment:
Visual studio 2022, v17.8.3 with net8 support

I did cleanup to c# solution with 6 projects using profile2 .

I found that vs 2022 during code cleanup using profile2  add these like comments:

```
/* Unmerged change from project 'xxxx (net6.0)'
Before:
foreach (var word in words)
After:
foreach (string word in words)
*/
```

Many of my source code files have these comments.

**My Question:**

- Why code cleanup add theses comments and what is its advantage?
- How to stop visual studio 2022 adding comments, e.g using editorconfig file?
- Is there a quick way to remove these comments or i have to undo all changes using git?

Comment: Looks like a bug into `dotnet format` https://github.com/dotnet/format/issues/1634

Comment: @seg, yes the issue is open since june 2022 and not resolved yet. BTW i have my own comments in this issue :).

Comment: It is necessary for us to provide feedback to the visual studio community